# Rails - Creating multiple models in one controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-4

This is more of a design then a technical issue..
I'm pretty new to Rails and trying to follow it's guidelines:

I have a a model called "Foo" along with "FooController" and a "UserForm.html.erb" to create new Foo objects which redirects to `FooController#create`..
When a user fills up a text field in the form and submits it the "create" action is called in the FooController class where the Foo model is persisted to the DB.

Well this is all pretty simple until I added a new model called "Bar":
The bar model has nothing in common with "Foo" apart from the form that submits them both (The "UserForm.html.erb") now theres some logic and if a user enters a special string like "Create Bar!" then a Bar instance should be created and persisted.
At first I thought about creating a new BarController and redirecting to `BarController#create` from `FooController#create` using the `redirect_to` method if the input string is right but this just seems downright ugly..

Something like this:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   def create
      if(params[:user_input] != "CreateBar!"
         redirect_to bar_create_path
      else
         Foo.create()
   end
end
```

So now I'm thinking about creating the Bar object in the `FooController#create` action but it's still a little bit weird to have a controller which is responsible for a single model to create some other model just because they are both bound by the View:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
   def create
      if(params[:user_input] != "CreateBar!"
         Bar.create()
      else
         Foo.create()
   end
end
```

I guess both ways would work, but what is the right rails way? Maybe there is a third way i didn't thought about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a controller just to create a model. You can create both models in the same controller and they will work.

As an example read this:

[Multiple Forms on one Ruby page using Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291080/multiple-forms-on-one-ruby-page-using-rails-4)

Which has a similar problem:

```
def update foo_bar
  if params[:bar]
    @foo = Bar.new(strong_foo_params)
    if @bar.save
       #whatever
    else
       #errors
    end
  else
    #actions for bar
  end
end
```

Caution:

If you are going to create both entries at the same time you have to wrap this on a transaction or take in account that one model can be saved and other might not.

Another option is to ask for .valid before saving.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to also put an explicit database transaction around this, as to prevent ending up with a succeeded foo.save and a not succeeded bar.save...

Comment: I didn't understand that he wanted to create both models at the same time. But if he want's he's gonna need it.